# How call outter javascript function from dynatree event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dynatree

I use Jquery dynatree and I need call my function from dynatree event `onSelect`.
Example:

```
 <script>
    function fillAdditionCheckboxes(node){
             ....
    }

    $(".dynatree-wrapper", this.el).dynatree({
        narrowSearchProgress : false,
        clickFolderMode: 1,
        checkbox: false,
        children: root.children,
        selectMode:1,
        onSelect:function (flag, node) {
            //how I can call my function ????
            fillAdditionCheckboxes(node);
        }
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, why are you using `"narrowSearchProgress : false"`?  That's not a valid parameter. [See the documentation](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html).

What's your problem?  Is the dynatree getting created?  Are you able to select items?

```
<script>
  function fillAdditionCheckboxes(node){
         ....
  }

  $(".dynatree-wrapper", this.el).dynatree({
      narrowSearchProgress : false,
      clickFolderMode: 1,
      checkbox: false,
      children: root.children,
      selectMode:1,
      onSelect:function (flag, node) {
          fillAdditionCheckboxes(node);
      }
  });
</script>
```